# How do I remove duplicate subcategories in Prestashop v1.5.3.1

Tags: database, themes, prestashop

Hello I manually created all my categories and subcategories in the back office. I have duplicate subcategories appearing underneath all categories in the front office. How do I remove the duplicate subcategories in Prestashop v1.5.3.1? I've looked in the categories.tpl and did not see anything that calls for duplicate subcategories. Where else do I need to look and what do I need to change to prevent the duplicate subcategories from showing in the front office Prestashop v1.5.3.1? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the classes/Category.php  search for function "getSubCategories" . There you will have a mysql query. It will be like

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
        SELECT c.*, cl.id_lang, cl.name ... ...
```

Change it to

```
$result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
        SELECT DISTINCT c.*, cl.id_lang, cl.name,
```

You just need to place **DISTINCT** after **SELECT** and before **c.*** .

I hope it will work. If not then let me know.

Thank you